# Which agent executes a command given to an agentset first?

Tags: netlogo

If I switch to turtle/patch context and do something like "set pcolor green", in what order do they execute the commands? I tested it out with a wait in there to see if there was an obvious pattern, but couldn't notice any. Is there any difference between that and ask?

I doubt it's completely random, though. How's it actually being handled behind the stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's random--about as random as things get in computer programming, I believe. The NetLogo User Manual says:

> An agentset is not in any particular order. In fact, it's always in a random order. And every time you use it, the agentset is in a different random order. This helps you keep your model from treating any particular turtles, patches or links differently from any others (unless you want them to be). Since the order is random every time, no one agent always gets to go first.

I just looked quickly at AgentSet.java in the source code for a recent version of NetLogo (5.0.2), it and looks to me like the order is randomized using a Mersenne Twister algorithm, which is usually considered to be quite good for randomization.

If you want the turtles/patches/links in a particular order, you can use `sort`, or select elements using e.g. `with`, or convert the agentset into a list using `[self] of <agentset>`, for example.

Comment: Hmm.  Blob, did I misunderstand your question?  I thought you were asking what order elements from an agentset are taken, but now that I reread your question, it looks like you might be asking about the order of commands in a block.  Those are sequential, of course.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, but no; you answered my question.